# System.ComponentModel.InotifyPropertyChanging error

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I am developing a windows form app that will need to run on a production machine that is only running .net 2.0.

in this project i am, however, using some 3.0+ related classes (ie linq) , therefore even know i have set the target framework to 2.0 in visual studio, i have copied all 3.0+ related dlls to to production server but i am getting the following error when i am working with multi threating  any idea why ?

```
System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging' from assembly 'System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

here are the list of dlls i have copied to release folder

- System.dll
- System.Core.dll
- System.Data.dll
- System.Data.Linq.dll
- System.Deployment.dll
- System.Windows.Forms.dll

as you can see i have copied the latest version of System.dll to the target folder but the app seems to be using the one installed on machine and ignore mine

any help would greatly be appreciated

thanks

Comment: After some more investigation this seems to be related to linq to sql . but again the app should really be using the system.dll i have provided not the system machine :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok this seems to work :)

[Assembly Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

That interface was added to System.dll in a service pack; 2.0 SP 1 (also shipped with .Net 3.5); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanging(v=VS.90).aspx

It cannot work on vanilla 2.0.

Either install the 2.0 SP 1 service pack (or 3.5), or live without it.

Comment: In either case, you *should* install the latest SP. The original .NET 2 had some weird issues.

Comment: Hey marc, if i could update the server i would :). i have copied the new version of dll and promoted to production along side of my appliction the problem is, the app is still using the system.dll that is installed on the machine and ignore mine. i am looking for a way to have it use the system.dll i have provided it instead of machines

Comment: @Amir - if it strict 2.0 you'll have to go without then